# Decimal places not being returned from SQL Stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

**Situation**

As the question says, I have a program and upon entering a value, this value is sent to my store procedure and 80 and 20% is calculated and returned via out parameter.

**Problem**

The problem is, despite how I think that my code should be working, the decimal place isn't returned when calculating my 80 and 20 percent. I have looked over the code and running the code in SQL manager works correctly, I just cant get the correct values into my C# Application.

C# Code

```
        decimal fl_covByA;
        decimal fl_covByB;
        using (Bookstore_DBEntities x = new Bookstore_DBEntities())
        {


            ObjectParameter covByIndiv = new ObjectParameter("covByIndiv", typeof(decimal));
            ObjectParameter covByIns = new ObjectParameter("covByIns", typeof(decimal)); 
            x.cal_InsCoverage(cla_bookDetails.cost,covByIndiv, covByIns); //Breakpoint shows values without decimals
            fl_covByB = (decimal)covByIndiv.Value;
            fl_covByA = (decimal)covByIns.Value;
        }
```

Store Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[cal_InsCoverage]
@cost numeric(18,2),
@covByIndiv numeric(18,2) OUT,
@covByIns numeric(18,2) OUT
AS
SELECT @covByIndiv=(@cost*20)/100,@covByIns=(@cost*80)/100
GO
```

If I pass in a cost of 100.25 I get 20.05   80.20 in my query results but according to my break point i get 20 and 80. So any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Per [this forum](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22675737/Retrieving-a-Decimal-OUTPUT-parameter-value-from-a-SQL-Stored-Procedure.html) post, it seems you will need to specify the precision/scale of your two output parameters, in .NET. So try adding this: `.Parameters("@covByIndiv").Precision=18
.Parameters("@covByIndiv").Scale=2
.Parameters("@covByIns").Precision=18
.Parameters("@covByIns").Scale=2
`. If that works, I will provide it as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you pass a decimal parameter to a SQL Server stored procedure you must set the Precision and Scale of the parameter, otherwise it defaults to scale of 0, which strips off the decimal portion.  Your ObjectParameter class probably has Precision and Scale properties, or you can google "how to set precision and scale on ObjectParameter" and find proper means.

Comment: Can you assist in setting precision and scale? ObjectParameter doesnt have a Precision and Scale.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this forum post](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22675737/Retrieving-a-Decimal-OUTPUT-parameter-value-from-a-SQL-Stored-Procedure.html), it seems you will need to specify the precision and scale of your two output parameters, in .NET.

So try adding this:

```
.Parameters("@covByIndiv").Precision=18
.Parameters("@covByIndiv").Scale=2

.Parameters("@covByIns").Precision=18
.Parameters("@covByIns").Scale=2
```

If that doesn't help, try changing your types from `numeric(18,2)` to `decimal(18,2)`. Perhaps EF will handle the decimal type better.

Comment: Im still a little confused with this, the ObjectParameter doesnt have a Parameter attribute.

Comment: From googling around it looks like your version of EntityFramework simply does not work with decimal parameters that need to set scale.  I found one post that says you can hack the edmx file and add those attributes.  But if you have a choice you would probably be better off switching to using an ADO Command object.  Here is a link to someone who tried hacking the edmx file (note this will break when you update the edmx):  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14bdde82-c084-44dd-ad83-c1305cb966d2/decimal-output-parameter-rounded-to-integer?forum=adodotnetentityframework.

Comment: Agree with @TomRegan. Not a fan of EDMX hacking.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Use decimal math instead of integer math.

`SELECT @covByIndiv=(@cost*20.0)/100.0,@covByIns=(@cost*80.0)/100.0`

Comment: No this wouldn't work, besides the decimal exist in SQL just not returned in C#

Comment: Yes I see.  I think @Nicholas V. has the right answer.

Comment: if you cant' get it working correctly maybe you can just multiply the results by whatever precision you want and then convert it on your client code.  This is the textbook definition of `hack` but it would probably solve your particular problem.  I would not recommend it generally.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the stored procedure to return my decimal place not matter what I tried.

So I did what I always knew I could do, I scrapped the stored procedure and just did the math in the code. Though I would like to know how I could solve that issue instead of doing a by pass but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Use the Float type

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the FLOAT type. In VB.Net I do this:
cmdSQL1.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@VAT", SqlDbType.Float)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Answer (score 0):

We have to aply two chnages

1. In Our SQL server Table Field the field type must be Float or
   Numeric(N,M) where N= digits  and M=decimals
2. In our C# code we have to declare the **SQLvalueType(SqlDbType.Float)**
   and the  **DbType.Double**.

In The following example i use a SQL Procedure by returning the Average of the 6 previous records , which I believe is useful  and the c# main code to retrieve the field value.

```
/****** The SQL PROCEDURE ******/  

USE [PYTHION17]  
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[P_GIP_AVG]    Script Date: 
25/1/2022 3:13:57 μμ ******/  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE **`[dbo].[P_GIP_AVG]`**
@PF7 NVARCHAR(45), @PF1 NVARCHAR(5), @PF24 DATE, @PGip_avg float  OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @PGip_avg = (SELECT  AVG(CAST(ST.ss AS Float)) AS Expr3
FROM         (
SELECT      TOP 6 f7, AVG(G_Goals) AS ss, f24
FROM         (SELECT      f7, g_goals, f24, f1
FROM         (SELECT      f7, G_Goals, f24, F1, row_number() OVER 
(PARTITION BY f7,F1
ORDER BY f24 DESC) AS rn
FROM  T_MAIN) AS sub
WHERE      rn < 7 AND f7 = @PF7 AND f1 = @PF1 AND F24 < @PF24 ) AS dt
GROUP BY f7, f24 ORDER BY F7 ) AS ST)

if @PGip_avg IS NULL 
begin
set  @PGip_avg = 0
end
return  @PGip_avg
END
```

The C# Code

```
public void P_Update_DataH(int P_aa, string PF1, DateTime PDATE, string 
PF7)
{
SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand("P_GIP_AVG", cons);
cmds.ResetCommandTimeout();
cmds.CommandTimeout = 0;
cmds.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PF24", SqlDbType.Date).Value = PDATE;
cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PF1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = PF1;
cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PF7", SqlDbType.Text).Value = PF7;

**cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PGip_avg", SqlDbType.Float);
cmds.Parameters("@PGip_avg").DbType = DbType.Double;**
*cmds.Parameters("@PGip_avg").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;*

cons.Open();


cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();

**S_G_GOALS = FormatNumber(cmds.Parameters("@PGip_avg").Value, 2);**

try
{
    var sqlText = "UPDATE [CURRENT_DAY] Set  [G_GLS_MO] = @PS_G_GOALS WHERE 
[aa] = @aa ";
    using (var cnConnect = new SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cm = new SqlCommand(sqlText, cnConnect))
        {
            SqlCommand command = cons.CreateCommand();
            cnConnect.Open();
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aa", SqlDbType.Int).Value = P_aa;
            cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PS_G_GOALS", 
SqlDbType.Float).Value = S_G_GOALS;

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ii += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("    PDATE:  " + PDATE + "    " + S_G_GOALS);
            cnConnect.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("  Exception Type: {0}" + "     ex.Message    " + 
ex.Message + "     ex.StackTrace    " + ex.StackTrace);
}
finally
{
    cons.Close();
}

return 1;
}
```

I hope I contributed in someway to this problem.

Thank you for your time.